# Setting up a RAIDed Swap Partition

Tags: raid, swap, cryptswap

I have a highly customized procedure to install Ubuntu in an encrypted ZFS file system, and RAIDed drives. A description of the installation procedure can be downloaded here:

https://www.mediafire.com/file/2w8mdb96tbzslub/Ubuntu_22.04_Root_on_ZFS_Encryption.odt/file

I got Ubuntu working fine in most respects, but I was not able to configure the swap partition. The partition was created with the statements:

```
sgdisk     -n 2:0:+256G    -t 2:FD00 $SSD1
sgdisk     -n 2:0:+256G    -t 2:FD00 $SSD2
```

The swap configure attempt was done with the command sequence:

```
apt install --yes cryptsetup mdadm
mdadm --create /dev/md0 --metadata=1.2 --level=mirror \
    --raid-devices=2 ${SSD1}-part2 ${SSD2}-part2
```

This result of the last command above was the error message:

```
mdadm: super1.x cannot open /dev/disk/by-id/nvme-eui.002538ba11517132-part2: # # Device or resource busy
mdadm: /dev/disk/by-id/nvme-eui.002538ba11517132-part2 is not suitable for this array.
mdadm: super1.x cannot open /dev/disk/by-id/nvme-eui.002538ba11505423-part2: Device or resource busy
mdadm: /dev/disk/by-id/nvme-eui.002538ba11505423-part2 is not suitable for this array.
mdadm: create aborted
```

How does one make these partitions not busy? I cannot figure how it be busy because in the installation procedure I do not see anything done that would make it busy. They have not been used for anything up to that point.

Is the partition not suitable only because it is busy? Is the type FD00 (Linux Raid type) appropriate for a RAIDed swap partition? I also tried type BF02 which is the Solaris swap type, but I got the same resulting error.

Comment: Why do you  need a swap partition? Do you want to set up hibernate or suspend to disk? If not, you may consider using a swap file. Recent versions of Ubuntu use a swap file instead of a partition.

Comment: Is swap partitioning no longer supported in Ubuntu?  Is that why my attempt at a swap partition fails?

I created a partition intended for swap because I was not aware it was possible to have a swap file, and a partition for it was part of the procedure I based my own procedure on Step 2.4:
https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Getting%20Started/Ubuntu/Ubuntu%2022.04%20Root%20on%20ZFS.html#step-4-system-configuration . I do favor a file instead of a partition because a partition is size limited, and a file is more open ended in its size.

Comment: Swap partition is supported. I am not sure how to do it in zfs RAID1.

Answer (score 0):

I was able create a working swap file. The procedure I followed for doing this is at:
https://github.com/zfsonlinux/pkg-zfs/wiki/HOWTO-use-a-zvol-as-a-swap-device

Thank you everyone for your very helpful comments.